# How to split live data into bar graph

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a tracker looking for specific words in tweets. When a search word is found it prints "Word: 1" or "Word: 2" depending on how many times it finds a specific word. So if I am searching for the words ("Python", "Code", "Snake") and each word was said x times the output would look similar to this:

```
Python: 4
Code: 7
Snake: 2
```

Now I want to live graph this data as it comes in into a bar graph. So somehow I want to split the data and get the "Word" on the x axis and the # on the y.

Here is code for incoming data from tweepy ([link](https://pastebin.com/ddLvs2Xn)):

```
from collections import Counter
import collections
from list import *
import json
import tweepy

def on_status(self, tweet, word_counts=Counter()):
    lines = tweet.text.split("\n")
    for line in lines:
        words = {"Python", "Snake", "Code"}  # words to keep counts for
        tweets = tweet.text
        tracked_words = [word for word in line.split() if word in words]
        word_counts.update(tracked_words)
        print(
            *[f"{word}: {word_counts[word]}" for word in set(tracked_words)],
            sep=", ",
        )
        print(
            "Tracked Words:" + str(tracked_words)
        )  # Prints word found in tweet such as "Snake"
        print(
            "Word Counts:" + str(word_counts)
        )  # Printers Counter({Total # of words tracked})
```

Code for trying to graph plot ([link](https://pastebin.com/imvt97w5)):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from NewGraph import *

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
langs = [str(tracked_words)]
students = [int(tracked_words)]
ax.bar(langs, students)
plt.show()
```

*Note: I am trying to get this in real-time, so theoretically I could leave the program for days and it collects and graphs data